How can I have a JSDoc interface with static properties & methods?
The following is an interface.
/**
 * @interface
 */
class ISomething {
  /**
   * @return {number}
   */
  static aMethod() {
    throw new Error('not implemented');
  }

  /**
   * @type {Object}
   */
  static property;
}

The following is an implementation, and no errors happen if I don't add the static items.
/**
 * @implements {ISomething}
 */
class Implementation {
  // forgot to implement the static items
  // no errors in VSCode
}

What I want is to similar to how interfaces work but for static items that can be accessed with respect to the class instead of object. I want some error if I forget to implement a static method. Any workarounds and hacks are appreciated.

You have added the tag typescript yet you do not appear to be using TypeScript at all. Is there a good reason why you can't in this situation?

JavaScript does not support interfaces. See for more information: Does JavaScript have the interface type (such as Java's 'interface')?
You can use TypeScript, which does support interfaces: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html
If you are already using TypeScript, do not declare the interface using JSDoc and rather like this:
interface ISomething {}


I'm using JSDoc in .js files and VSCode checks interfaces via JSDoc, I'm not using typescript

VSCode has some plugins to check documentation, but it won't create errors in JavaScript, because JavaScript does not support interfaces, so it is not invalid code to not implement the static method.

As stated by @Tim Hansen Javascript doesn't have interfaces and Typescript has better type support than JSDoc. Hence I've created a workaround function that checks for proper implementation of static members at runtime.
You can create a script that imports your JS classes and if you've forgotten to implement any static memeber, error will be thrown when you run it.
Usage of workaround
/**
 * @interface
 */
class ISomething {
  /**
   * @return {number}
   */
  static aMethod() {
    throw new Error('not implemented');
  }

  /**
   * @type {Object}
   */
  static property;
}


/**
 * @implements {ISomething}
 */
class Implementation {
  // forgot to implement the static items
  // no errors in VSCode
  // enforce fn throws error
}

enforceInterfaceStaticMembers(Implementation, ISomething);

Workaround function
function enforceInterfaceStaticMembers(className, interfaceName) {
  const classStatics = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(className);
  const interfaceStatics = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(interfaceName);

  interfaceStatics.forEach((prop) => {
    if (!classStatics.includes(prop)) {
      throw new Error(
        `${className.name} must implement static member: ${interfaceName.name}.${prop}`
      );
    }

    const interfaceType = typeof interfaceName[prop];
    const classType = typeof className[prop];

    if (classType !== interfaceType) {
      throw new Error(
        `${className.name}'s static member '${prop}' must have the same type as in the interface (expected ${interfaceType}, found ${classType}).`
      );
    }
  });
}

